# Jquery accordion plugin

Tags: jquery, header, icons, accordion

I am use Jquery accordion plugin.
I need to use my own header icons,
according to doc, i need to create css class with background image.

so i did this in my css file.

```
.normal_arrow {
    background : url(../images/arrowonly.jpg);
}

.circle_arrow {
    background : url(../images/circle_arrow.jpg);
}

.circle_arrow_down {
    background : url(../images/circle_arrow_down.jpg);
}
```

then in javascript:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    header: "h3",
    clearStyle: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    icons: {
        header: "normal_arrow",
        headerSelected: "circle_arrow_down"               
    }
});
```

but there is no arrows showed up.

Comment: I fixed your code for you. In the future just put 4 spaces before every line of code to have it show nicely formatted.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem, I had to use position:absolute; to make the icon container take a width and a height.

```
.normal_arrow {
    background : url(../images/arrowonly.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks correct.

Try using `background-image:` instead of `background:`

Also use a tool like [`Firebug`](http://getfirebug.com/) to make absolutely sure the relatives paths are going where you think they are going.

Answer (score 1):

Use `!important`:

```
.normal_arrow {
    background : url(../images/arrowonly.jpg) !important;
}
```

because you need to overwrite the default style.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS use background-image and in the JavaScript you need to put header and headerSelected in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect use of background. For that to render probably either use

```
background-image: url(../images/circle_arrow.jpg);
```

**or**

```
background: transparent url(../images/circle_arrow.jpg) top left no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** this is only for users who are NOT using any jquery styling. (ie) you didn't include jquery's css in the file.

the default style in the CSS is this:

```
.ui-icon { display: none; text-indent: -99999px; overflow: hidden; background-repeat:  no-repeat; }
```

So if you set up a div with a background image, width and height, but it still won't show up, its because of the above class.

Add this to your document:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-icon { display: block; }

</style>
```